# Применить стиль к TreeViewItem с определенным Tag

Tags: c#, wpf

Пробую так, но ничего не происходит:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="Tag" Value="tube"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Image Name="img"
                                   Width="20"
                                   Height="20"
                                   Stretch="Fill"
                                   Source="icon.ico"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>

                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: @Koddi, вставил код в свой проект и заменил файл картинки. использовал не ico а png. все работает. может в этом и проблема...
Нет.... и с ico все в порядке

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Если TreeViewItem добавлять непосредственно из Code-Behind то триггеры не срабатывают. Если в XAML задавать TreeViewItem то все работает.

Добавляю в Code-Behind так:
var item = (TreeViewItem) e.OriginalSource;
var itemTube = new TreeViewItem
{
    Tag = "tube",
    Header = "Труба № " + _mySqlDataReader.GetString(0)
}; 
item.Items.Add(itemTube);

Comment: Решил проблему добавлением параметра ItemContainerStyle = treeView1.ItemContainerStyle у родительского TreeViewItem.